# Weird Error: No method 'find'?

Tags: meteor

I'm receiving a very weird error:

`Exception from sub sda4Ho8DT6MXTKjvb TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'find'
I20140728-11:22:25.248(-4)?     at null._handler (app/server/publications.js:4:18)`

This is my code. Very simple pub/sub. No idea why I get this error.

publications.js

```
Meteor.publish('assets', function() {
    //query = query || {};
    //query.removed = false;
    return Assets.find();
});
```

assets_col.js

```
Assets = new Meteor.Collection('assets');
```

router.js

```
waitOn: function() {
    return Meteor.subscribe('assets');
}
```

Comment: Where is your assets_col.js file located? It should be in a shared directory.

Comment: My guess is that you may be conflicting with Meteor own Assets object, try changing your collection name. http://docs.meteor.com/#assets

Comment: It's located in my common directory. So, it should be fine. I'm guessing it's conflicting as @saimeunt suggested. I'll rename the collection and see how it goes.

Comment: Thank you very much @saimeunt. That was indeed the problem!